# What does SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS prevent?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS - The system does not display the
>   critical-error-handler message box. Instead, the system sends the
>   error to the calling process.

However, `SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)` already suppresses all error dialogs.

So what exactly does SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS prevent?

From the documentation it is not very clear, and when testing by setting and unsetting `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS`, it did not make a difference for access violations, division by zero, unhandled C++ exceptions, or anything else I could think of.

Comment: If you try to access a file or directory on a disk drive with no media in it (e.g. an empty floppy drive) you will get one of these errors. Not sure what other conditions generate it.

Comment: This is an extension to the infamous MS-Dos "Abort, Retry, Fail" error prompt.  Exactly what Microsoft considers "critical system errors" is not documented.  It only documents that you should use SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS to turn it off so these mystifying message boxes don't pop up.  The errors you listed are not system errors, they are program errors.  Try SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX instead.

Answer (score 2):

System errors that the `SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX` flag prevent include:

- Dynamic link errors when loading a DLL (Entry Point Not Found for example).

[image: Entry Point Not Found]

- Application initialization errors

[image: Application Error]